# How to create a row number that infer the group it belongs to from another column? Want to do it in both pandas and postgresql/sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

UPDATE: SQL solution provided below, but pandas solution not yet. Appreciate if anyone has a pandas solution.

I have a table/pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

Where the first row of each user is always a new group, indicated by 'new', then the next row could be in the same group (indicated by 'same') or a new group (indicated by 'new').

I want to add a column group_number, that would create a number for each row related to its group, such that all rows of the first group of a user would be 1, all rows of the second group of the user would be 2, etc. It would then look like this in my example:

[image]

I can do it in pandas while iterating on the rows like the below code, but it would be great if there is a vectorized solution?:

```
group_number=[]
current_user=-1

for index, row in myDF.iterrows():    
    if row['user']!=current_user:
        group_number.append(1)
        counter=1
        current_user=row['user']
    elif row['group']=='same' :
        group_number.append(counter)
    else:
        counter+=1
        group_number.append(counter)

myDF['group_number']=group_number
```

(Side note that may or may not be relevant: I think this problem has some flavor of the gaps and islands structure/problem, but it is a bit different (I believe it is a bit more general))

How do I create that group_number in postgresql/sql and in pandas (a vectorized solution)?

Comment: How would you guarantee the correct order in which the rows are retrieved from the table? As is there's no information you could use to `ORDER` the columns `BY`, so there's no way to reliably reproduce the same result over independent queries – and thus no way to reliably assign rows to groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is indeed another column to order by. I just didn’t include it as I thought (wrongly so) that it won’t be used here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres SQL, we can just take a window count of "new" rows per user. Assuming that you have a column to order your records, say `id`:

```
select t.*,
    count(*) filter(where grp = 'new') over(partition by usr order by id) rn
from mytable t
order by usr, id
```

I renamed the table columns to `mytable(usr, grp)` (since `user` and `group` are SQL keywords). The new group number comes out in third column `rn`.

Comment: Though we rely entirely on database providing appropriately sorted data, don't we? But I don't see how we'd achieve that if there aren't yet other columns providing appropriate criteria...

Comment: @Aconcagua: the database does not provide "sorted data" whatsoever. From its perspective, a table is just a bunch of rows with no specific ordering. If you want a *stable*, repeatable result, then you need some column to actually `order by` - otherwise the order is not guaranteed. It can *happen* to seem stable, but it might as well not be.

Comment: I'm fully aware of, and that exactly was my point: No stable (reproducible) results possible. So wouldn't we rather have to hint to the questionable, if not flawed design?

Comment: @Aconcagua: oh ok, so we agree, since that's mentioned in my question. Now, from my experience of such question, there is usually such a column in the table, but OP did not disclose it because they might initially think it is not relevant for the question.

Comment: *''since that's mentioned im my \[answer\]'* – ah, too much focus on the query, too little on the surrounding text on my side ;) Still, remains a critical issue, maybe a good idea to append the `ORDER BY` to make it more explicit to the user how crucial that is.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. There is indeed another column to order by. I just didn’t include it as I thought (wrongly so) that it won’t be used here!

Comment: Any input on how to do this in pandas?

Comment: @Aly: I have no knowledge in pandas, sorry!

Comment: @Aly Me not either :(

Comment: Any idea how this would look like in mySql as it seems like such expression with filter might not work there?

Comment: @Aly: your question mentions Postgres, so the query is for that database. In MySQL: `sum(grp = 'new') over(partition by usr order by id) rn`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Did that now!