# What is the pandas equivalent to a sql count window function with a filter?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the pandas equivalent to a sql count window function with a filter. Here is the sql query:

```
select t.*,
    count(*) filter(where grp = 'new') over(partition by usr order by id) rn
from mytable t
order by usr, id
```

I tried the below after sorting by id:

```
mytable['rn'] = mytable.groupby('usr')['grp'].transform('count')
```

But it is wrong as I am not filtering on grp as I should and I don't know how to do such filter. So, what is the correct pandas equivalent (a vectorized solution)?

Note: For more context, if needed, you can refer to this question, but you don't have to:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364851/how-to-create-a-row-number-that-infer-the-group-it-belongs-to-from-another-colum)

Comment: AFAIK only Postgres supports that expression. That will fail in all other SQL dialects! An equivalent would be running on a `CASE` expression. And usually you would use `ROW_NUMBER()` for running counts.

Comment: Could you please specify how the sql query using case and row_number()  would be in such case?

Comment: Actually, here is the expression for MySql (thanks to the answer to the question in the link I had in the question above):
sum(grp = 'new') over(partition by usr order by id) rn

Still, what is the pandas vectorized equivalent to such sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
d = {"new": 0, "same": 1}
​
mytable["group_number"] = (
    mytable.groupby("user", group_keys=False)["group"]
        .apply(lambda s: s.map(d).diff().eq(-1).cumsum().add(1))
)
```

Output :
​

```
print(mytable)

    user group  group_number
0      1   new             1
1      1  same             1
2      1  same             1
3      1   new             2
4      1  same             2
5      1   new             3
6      2   new             1
7      2  same             1
8      2   new             2
9      2  same             2
10     3   new             1
11     3  same             1
```

*Input used :*

```
mytable = pd.DataFrame(
    {"user": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
     "group": ["new", "same", "same", "new", "same",
               "new", "new", "same", "new", "same", "new", "same"]}
)
```

Comment: Could you explain the solution a bit, please?
Also, is that the simplest solution to this? There is no easier way of adding the filter somehow to my attempted solution?

Comment: If it's not the simplest/easiest of the possible solutions, it is one of them. We just create a mapper `d` to use arithmetic and compute the difference between each `group` (same, new). If the difference is equal to `-1` (*which means a transition same=>new*), we increment by 1, otherwise we keep the actual group number. And of course, we do that for each group of users (1, 2, 3, ..) separately.

Comment: In SQL query, *same* grouping would return NULL with no running count (i.e., Postgres' `filter`).

Comment: Isn't this solution (using .apply) non-vectorized though? (my understanding is that .apply with lambda will iterate on each row; a similar fashion to iterating on rows using .iterrows in a for loop, so it is not a vectorized solution).

Is there a vectorized solution?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the equivalent SQL standard expression:

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN grp = 'new'
  THEN ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY usr, ORDER BY id) 
END rn
```

Pandas equivalence would be:

```py
mytable['rn'] = (
    mytable.assign(
        grp_flag = lambda df: (               # CASE
            df["grp"].eq('new').astype('Int64').replace(0, np.nan)
        )
    ).sort_values(['usr', 'grp_flag', 'id'])  # ORDER BY
    .groupby(['usr', 'grp_flag'])             # PARTITION BY
    .cumcount().add(1)                        # ROW_NUMBER
)

mytable['rn'] = mytable['rn'].ffill()         # FILL NANs
```

Comment: This seems to have NaN for each that don't have 'new', while we wanted to them to have the same count of the latest 'new' row above them. Is there a way to edit your solution to reflect this? Also, could you please explain what .astype('Int64') is doing here and why it is needed? And also what exactly .cumcount().add(1) is doing?

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired result for [mre]? [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, `astype('Int64')` converts the boolean flag to a nullable integer type. As commented, [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) mimics SQL's `ROW_NUMBER` for a group count which starts at 0 so we add 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. As for input and output, those of the other answer are perfectly accurate, but the answer itself is more complex than yours, so I was wondering if there is a single answer that mimics the sql query and gives correct expected output?

Comment: Also, wanted to add that this answer is vectorized so probably better than the one below uses .apply. However, this answer to be adjusted to reflect what needs to be done as I mentioned above. Still not sure how to do that and would appreciate your input on that. Thanks a lot!